# Extracting pairs of elements from two Matlab vectors satisfying some criteria

Tags: arrays, matlab

Consider three row vectors in Matlab, `A`, `B`, `C`, each with size `1xJ`. I want to construct a matrix `D` of size `Kx2` listing every possible pairs of elements `(a,b)` such that:

- `a` is an element of `A`.
- `b` is an element of `B`.
- `a-b` is an element of `C`.
- `a` and `b` are different from `Inf`, `-Inf`.

For example,

```
A=[-3 3 0 Inf -Inf];
B=[-2 2 0 Inf -Inf];
C=[Inf -Inf -1 1 0];
D=[-3 -2;  %-3-(-2)=-1
    3 2;   % 3-2=1
    0 0];  % 0-0=0
```

I would like this code to be efficient, because in my real example  I have to repeat it many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `J` is not too large so that you can afford two intermediate matrices of size up to `J`×`J`, this can be done in a vectorized way, which usually means it will be fast:

```
A = [-3 3 0 Inf -Inf];
B = [-2 2 0 Inf -Inf];
C = [Inf -Inf -1 1 0];
[a, b] = ndgrid(A(~isinf(A)), B(~isinf(B)));
ind = ismember(a-b, C);
result = [a(ind) b(ind)];
```

This works by generating all pairs that fulfil the *individual* conditions (such as being finite), and then selecting those pairs that fulfil the *joint* condition (such as their difference being in a prescribed set of values).

Comment: could you help me with this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69481450/extracting-positions-of-elements-from-two-matlab-vectors-satisfying-some-criteri?noredirect=1#comment122810124_69481450

Comment: @TEX It looks like you already got a solution :-)