# Extracting positions of elements from two Matlab vectors satisfying some criteria

Tags: arrays, matlab

Consider three row vectors in Matlab, `A`, `B`, `C`, each with size `1xJ`. I want to construct a matrix `D` of size `Kx3` listing every triplets `(a,b,c)` such that:

- `a` is the position in `A` of  `A(a)`.
- `b` is the position in `B` of    `B(b)`.
- `A(a)-B(b)` is an element of `C`.
- `c` is the position in `C` of `A(a)-B(b)`.
- `A(a)` and `B(b)` are different from `Inf`, `-Inf`.

For example,

```
A=[-3 3 0 Inf -Inf];
B=[-2 2 0 Inf -Inf];
C=[Inf -Inf -1 1 0];
D=[1 1 3;   %-3-(-2)=-1
   2 2 4;   % 3-2=1
   3 3 5];  % 0-0=0
```

I would like this code to be efficient, because in my real example  I have to repeat it many times.

This question relates to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480944/extracting-pairs-of-elements-from-two-matlab-vectors-satisfying-some-criteria), but now I'm looking for the positions of the elements.

Comment: This could become very computationally expensive if `A` and `B` become large, are there any constraints on what the values could be or how big these are? Otherwise there could quickly become lots of possible pairings of elements of `A` and `B` to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `combvec` (or [any number of alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7446946/3978545)) to get all pairings of indices `a` and `b` for the corresponding arrays `A` and `B`. Then it's simply a case of following your criteria

1. Find the differences
2. Check which differences are in `C`
3. Remove elements you don't care about

Like so:

```
% Generate all index pairings
D = combvec( 1:numel(A), 1:numel(B) ).';
% Calculate deltas
delta = A(D(:,1)) - B(D(:,2));
delta = delta(:); % make it a column
% Get delta index in C (0 if not present)
[~,D(:,3)] = ismember(delta,C);
% If A or B are inf then the delta is Inf or NaN, remove these
idxRemove = isinf(delta) | isnan(delta) | D(:,3) == 0;
D(idxRemove,:) = [];
```

For your example, this yields the expected results from the question.

You said that `A` and `B` are at most 7 elements long, so you have up to 49 pairings to check. This isn't too bad, but readers should be careful that the pairings can grow quickly for larger inputs.

Comment: Thanks. I think this would work as well (taking inspiration from my previous question) `[a, b] = ndgrid(A(~isinf(A)), B(~isinf(B)));`
`[indAB, indC] = ismember(a-b, C);`
`[posA, posB]=find(indAB);`
`posC=nonzeros(indC);`
`D = [posA posB posC];`

Comment: This looks like pretty much the same logic, but you're filtering out the `inf` values up front, doing the `delta` in-line, and using `find` to get the non-zero indices output from `ismember`. So yes without running it myself that looks fine